# Can you use ionic capacitor run android and ionic cordova run android?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

just wanna know if you can you use ionic capacitor run android and ionic cordova run android at the same project?

Or do I have to use only one?

I am using Ionic 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capacitor and Cordova are two wrapper frameworks that can be used to build your ionic application on.
These are basically two routes, which should be decided at the beginning of the app. Difficult to change later.
Both of these have separate ways of building and deploying the app on actual devices, and you have to follow only one based on your framework.

Refer these links for more info on them
[Link1](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/android)
[Capacitor build flow](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/workflow)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to create separate project for capacitor, it have different dependency to build and run the app

Comment: https://medium.com/@sunilk/ionic-capacitor-vs-apache-cordova-difference-with-example-the-next-future-innovation-of-hybrid-93b1317e08cc